# Casting TResult in Task<TResult> to System.Object

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task

I am loading an assembly and calling a static method that will create a new object of type “MyClass1” (this type is specified at runtime) through reflection using MethodInfo.Invoke(). This works fine when the method is a normal sync method. However, the method being called is an async method which returns Task<MyClass1>, which will be used to retrieve the result using task.Result.

Ideally I should be using MyClass1 as TResult in the task, but the type is determined only at runtime so I can't do that. I am looking for a way to get the task and the result. I am trying to cast the TResult to System.Object and get the class as a generic Object. The following is the code I am using for this purpose.

```
public static void LoadAssembly()
{
    // Calling static async method directly works fine
    Task<MyClass1> task1 = MyClass1.MakeMyClass1();
    MyClass1 myClass1 = task1.Result;

    // Calling static async method through reflection through exception.
    Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(dllName);
    Type type = assembly.GetType("AsyncDll.MyClass1");
    var types = assembly.GetTypes(); 
    MethodInfo[] methodInfos = types[0].GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
    Type myClassType = types[0];
    MethodInfo mi = myClassType.GetMethod("MakeMyClass1");
    Object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(mi.ReflectedType);
    Task<Object> task = (Task<Object>)mi.Invoke(obj, null); // Exception occurs here.
    Object result = task.Result;
}
```

Following is the method (test code) being called through reflection. This

```
public class MyClass1
{
    public static async Task<MyClass1> MakeMyClass1()
    {
        MyClass1 newObject = null;
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            newObject = new MyClass1();
        });
        return newObject;
    }
    ...
}
```

Unfortunately, the casting of TResult is causing System.InvalidCastException.

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Test.exe

Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[MyClass1]' to type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Object]'.
```

How can I cast the TResult in Task<> to a generic object and get the result using task.Result? I would appreciate any help resolving this issue.

Comment: `types[0]` — you are setting yourself up for a bug. Search by name, or at least use `GetExportedTypes()` and check that there is just one of them. There are other unnecessary lines in your code, too.

Comment: `dynamic task = ...; var result = (Object) task.Result;` Or something like that.

Comment: This is a test code. In actual code I will use the name as suggested. Thanks again!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You cannot cast `Task<T>` to `Task<object>`, because `Task<T>` is not [covariant](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq.aspx) (it's not contravariant, either). The simplest solution would be to use some more reflection:

```
var task   = (Task) mi.Invoke (obj, null) ;
var result = task.GetType ().GetProperty ("Result").GetValue (task) ;
```

This is slow and inefficient, but usable if this code is not executed often. As an aside, what is the use of having an asynchronous `MakeMyClass1` method if you are going to block waiting for its result?

Comment: Why bother casting to Task at all?

Comment: Just as a precaution, and as a reminder of the exported method's contract.

Comment: Anton, Thanks a lot for your help. This solved my problem and I am able to get the object. Performance is not a concern in this case. This is a test tool not the actual consumer of the classes, which indeed uses this in proper async manner.

Answer (score 10):

As an enhancement to the accepted answer, you can avoid the blocking by awaiting the `Task` in between:

```
var task = (Task)mi.Invoke(obj, null);
await task;
var result = task.GetType().GetProperty("Result").GetValue(task);
```

Of course this will be properly asynchronous only if all methods up the call stack are marked `async` and you're using `await` instead of `.Result` everywhere.

Answer (score 8):

Another possibility is to write an extension method to this purpose:

```
    public static Task<object> Convert<T>(this Task<T> task)
    {
        TaskCompletionSource<object> res = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();

        return task.ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            if (t.IsCanceled)
            {
                res.TrySetCanceled();
            }
            else if (t.IsFaulted)
            {
                res.TrySetException(t.Exception);
            }
            else
            {
                res.TrySetResult(t.Result);
            }
            return res.Task;
        }
        , TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously).Unwrap();
    }
```

It is none-blocking solution and will preserve original state/exception of the Task.