# Calling Task<T> methods generically

Tags: c#, generics, async-await, task

Related to [Casting TResult in Task<TResult> to System.Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21805564/casting-tresult-in-tasktresult-to-system-object). I am building a generic async command execution function for a service.

The method to execute a generic command looks like this:

```
public async Task<object> ExecuteCommandAsync(string cmdName, CommandData data)
```

The code uses reflection to find a method on the class that has the given `cmdName`. Invoking this will return a `Type<T>` - we don't know the `T` in advance. However since `Task<T>` is not covariant, I cannot cast to `Task<object>`.

At present my solution (as per 21805564) is to call the Result method and encapsulate in a `Task.Run`, as shown below:

```
// find the method
MethodInfo cmd = GetMethod(cmdName);
var task = (Task)cmd.Invoke(this, data);
return await Task.Run<object>(() => { return task.GetType().GetProperty("Result").GetValue(task); });
```

My concern is that doing this negates the value of async: getting the result is now a blocking call so I might as well have used synchronous methods anyway.

Comment: Why don't you run your reflection code in a ContinueWith call? You'll probably want to call unwrap after ContinueWith to get the Task<object>

Comment: Is `T` one to one with `cmdName`?

Comment: @fsimonazzi not sure what you mean.

Comment: @KavehShahbazian No, the return types vary a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remember that `dynamic` is available. You can do something like this as long as you're not using `Microsoft.Bcl.Async`:

```
public async Task<dynamic> ExecuteCommandAsync(string cmdName, CommandData data)
{
  MethodInfo cmd = GetMethod(cmdName);
  dynamic task = cmd.Invoke(this, data);
  return await task;
}
```

In particular, I don't recommend using `Task.Run` because that would waste a thread, and I don't recommend using `Task.Result` because it will encapsulate any exceptions inside an `AggregateException`.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. Task.Run was the only way I could think to coerce the type at the time. I tweaked it slightly by casting the result, so it still returns object: ```return (object)(await task);```

Comment: @Quango: Consider changing the return type to `Task<dynamic>`. It may simplify your calling code.

Answer (score 5):

You can await the task and then reflect on the result once it has completed

```
public static async Task<object> AwaitResult(Task t)
{
    await t;
    return t.GetType().GetProperty("Result").GetValue(t, null);
}
```

Or:

```
return ((dynamic)t).Result;
```

Comment: Simple when you know how - which I clearly didn't! Many thanks @Lee