# why C# Func<interface> lambda expression requires cast for result

Tags: c#, lambda, task-parallel-library, func

I need to understand about Func type expression deeper.

```
public class TheResult : IResultEntry {
    ...
}
```

With above class, why does below second method require **cast**?

I can read the error message of course, but hard to understand.

```
// Success
public Task<IResultEntry> ProcessAsync_1()
{
    return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => (IResultEntry) new TheResult());
}

// Fail: Compiler error. Cannot implicitly convert...
public Task<IResultEntry> ProcessAsync_2()
{
    return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => new TheResult());
}
```

If we change it to named method with help of ReSharper, we can do without a cast.

```
public Task<IResultEntry> ProcessAsync_2_Changed()
{
    return Task.Factory.StartNew(function);
}

private IResultEntry function()
{
    return new TheResult();
}
```

Comment: you are expecting `IResultEntry` as a return value, but `TheResult` may implement other interfaces as well.

Comment: [Click](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21806002/1997232).

Comment: Just because two types, `A` and `B`, exhibit a certain inheritance/implementation relationship, that does *not* mean that `G<A>` and `G<B>` have the *same* relationship.

Comment: And also note that with `function()` you **do have a cast**, it's implicit but there it is.

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh  It's perfectly fine for `TheResult` to implement other interfaces. It's simply because making `Task` covarient would involve implementing `ITask<out T>`, which it doesn't. The dupe covers why it doesn't.