# How to call an async method and get a result back without using dynamics

Tags: c#, reflection, async-await

How to call an async method and get a result back without using dynamics

I want to call an async method with reflection. As I figured out there are two ways to do that

```
await (Task) objType.GetTypeInfo()
                    .GetDeclaredMethod("ThePrivateMethod")
                    .Invoke(theObject, null);
```

or

```
await (dynamic) objType.GetTypeInfo()
                       .GetDeclaredMethod("ThePrivateMethod")
                       .Invoke(theObject, null);
```

The Problem is if I don’t know the return type I need to do it like in the second example. But my problem is I can't use dynamics in my project. How can I call an async Method without knowing the return type and not using dynamics.

Comment: You can always cast to object.

Comment: perhaps object? or Jobject

Comment: can you please post a little more context? where will this await code be situated? " if I don’t know the return type " how does the async method where you call this code look like? signature? return type?

Comment: either [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21806002/5174469) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51621130/5174469) should be of help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Awaiting a `Task<T>` through reflection is going to be a real pain. Instead, you can split the problem: you already know how to await a `Task`, just manually retrieve the result afterwards:

```
var task = objType.GetTypeInfo()
    .GetDeclaredMethod("ThePrivateMethod")
    .Invoke(theObject, null);

await (Task)task;

var taskType = task.GetType();

if (taskType.IsGenericType && taskType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Task<>))
{
    var result = taskType.GetProperty("Result").GetValue(task);

    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

---

It looks like the framework sometimes returns a `Task<VoidTaskResult>` disguised as a `Task`. If that's a problem, you can filter them out:

```
var voidTaskResult = Type.GetType("System.Threading.Tasks.VoidTaskResult");


if (taskType.IsGenericType
    && taskType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Task<>)
    && taskType.GetGenericArguments()[0] != voidTaskResult)
{
    var result = task.GetType().GetProperty("Result").GetValue(task);

    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

Comment: is there some variation of `Task` where `IsGenericType` is false ?

Comment: @MongZhu Yes. A `Task<T>` derives from `Task`. `Task` is non-generic, and doesn't have a `Result` property.

Comment: Thx for that, very smart! little ugly I think there should be better support for that in the framework.

Comment: interesting why does such a signature `public async Task ThePrivateMethod()` result in `task.GetType().IsGenericType == true` but  `typeof(Task).IsGenericType == false` ?=!... confused

Comment: @MongZhu This is a surprising implementation detail, but an `async Task` method actually returns a `Task<VoidTaskResult>` instead of a `Task`

Comment: @MongZhu I edited the answer to show how to filter them

Comment: that is interesting. I just posted this as question. If you like to compose an aswer [there it is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52447267/why-does-type-isgenerictype-return-true-for-task-without-return-type-obtained-by)

Answer (score -1):

Although generic Task derived from Task, the result property only exists on the Task class definition. Further, since it’s not an interface, it cannot be covariant and so Task of X cannot be assigned to Task of object.

You will need to use dynamic or reflection, no way around it.

Simplest without using dynamic could look like

```
var task = (Task) objType.GetTypeInfo()
                .GetDeclaredMethod("ThePrivateMethod")
                .Invoke(theObject, null);

await task;

object result = task.GetType().GetProperty(“Result”).GetValue(task, null)
```

Answer (score -2):

would specifying it as object work?

```
   TheObjectClass theObject = new TheObjectClass();
    Type objType = typeof(TheObjectClass);
    object obj = objType.GetTypeInfo().GetDeclaredMethod("GetInt").Invoke(theObject, null);
    object val  = obj.GetType().GetProperty("Result").GetValue(obj);
    Type t = val.GetType();
    Console.WriteLine(t.Name);
```

Comment: await (object) ?
are you using the returned value?

Comment: this will throw an exception if there is no return value like in `async Task  ThePrivateMethod()`

Comment: have you tried not awaiting it, so it returns the Task and then await that
object aa = objType.GetTypeInfo()...
you may be able to inspect the task then..  just an idea

Comment: @Ian This doesn't work because `Task<T>` is not co-variant. Here's an [interesting project](https://github.com/jam40jeff/ITask) that addresses this.

Comment: @Ian Sure, but now you're not awaiting, but rather blocking on the result. [This is bad](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).

Comment: @spender this is not a practice I would use in production, but I suspect this is for unit testing.. and it achieves the request