# Why does Type.IsGenericType return TRUE for Task without return type obtained by reflection from method but typeof(Task).IsGenericTyp returns FALSE

Tags: c#, generics, task

Can someone explain this? Per documentation [IsGenericType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.isgenericparameter?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> indicatesing whether the current Type represents a type parameter in the definition of a generic type or method.

So this (LINQPad) code:

```
bool bStraight = typeof(Task).IsGenericType;
bStraight.Dump("typeof(Task).IsGenericType");
```

works as expected and yields the output:

> typeof(Task).IsGenericType
>   False

But when I retrieve it from a method by reflection:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public async Task Method()
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(3000);
        });
    }
}

public async Task TEST()
{
    MyClass theObject = new MyClass();

    Task task = (Task)typeof(MyClass).GetTypeInfo()
                            .GetDeclaredMethod("Method")
                            .Invoke(theObject, null);

    bool b = task.GetType().IsGenericType;  
    bool b2 = task.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Task<>);
    b.Dump("IsGenericType");
    b2.Dump("GetGenericTypeDefinition");

    bool bStraight = typeof(Task).IsGenericType;
    bStraight.Dump("typeof(Task).IsGenericType");
}
```

I get the unexpected output of :

> IsGenericType
>   True
>
> GetGenericTypeDefinition
>   True

Comment: Look closer at `task.GetType()` and you see that it's a `Task<VoidTaskResult>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In some situations, the framework returns a `Task<VoidTaskResult>` disguised as a `Task`. Imagine you have some logic relying on `TaskCompletionSource<T>`. If you don't actually intend to return a result, you still have to fill the `T` generic parameter. You could use `TaskCompletionSource<object>`, but you would be wasting a pointer worth of memory (4 bytes in 32 bit, 8 bytes in 64 bit). To avoid that, the framework uses an empty struct: `VoidTaskResult`.